# Retornar dos valores en el método ToString() Java POO

Tags: java, poo, clase

El día de hoy recurro a uds con el fin de que por favor me ayuden con esto.
Resulta que tengo una clase en Java llamada EstadoCargo.Tengo 2 variables y ambas son de tipo String. Quiero que el metodo Public String toString() me retorne ambas variables pero no me deja.

```
package package_empleado;


public class EstadoCargo {

    private String codigo;
    private String nombre;

    public EstadoCargo(String codigo, String nombre){
        setCodigo(codigo);
        setNombre(nombre);
    }      

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    //Este es el metodo
    public String toString(){
       return this.codigo;
       //return this.nombre
    }

}
```

De antemano muchas gracias!

Este es el código para subir los valores al Combo

```
  //ResultSet
     ResultSet estadoCargo;
    //Instancio la clase que contiene los metodos
    estadoCargo = objEmpleado.consultarEstadoCargo();
    try {
        //Recorremos el estado generado por la consulta de cargo
        while(estadoCargo.next()){
        //Recorremos el resultado generado por la consulta
        modelComboCargo.addElement(new EstadoCargo(estadoCargo.getString("codigo"), estadoCargo.getString("nombre")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos no cargados "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres hacer, pero un método sólo puede devolver un valor. Si quieres puedes concatenar ambos valores (`return this.codigo + this.nombre;`)

Comment: Como dice @PabloLozano solo puedes retornar un valor. Puedes concatenar los dos valores o devolver un objeto que contenga las dos variables y sobrescribir su método toString, poco más se puede hacer.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano el método toString DEBE devolver un String, ya que sobreescribes un método de Object

Comment: Te comento bien que es lo que quiero hacer. Resulta que quiero que se me retornen el nombre y el codigo para cargarlos a un ComboBox en Java. La solución tuya de concatenar sirvio pero el problema es que ahora en el Combo Box me aparecen los dos elementos es decir (1551-54cajero).

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Como se haría lo del objeto ? Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es usar los getters cuando generes el combobox para obtener el valor que necesites en cada momento.

Comment: @PabloLozano, por eso he puesto que se puede devolver un objeto sobreescribiendo su método ToString(); puede sobreescribir el método ToString del objeto para devolver un string con los dos valores concatenados (que es básicamente igual que concatenar los 2 valores sin haber creado el objeto). Solo daba otra opción. Aunque no encuentro del todo sentido a lo que pide.

Comment: Me permito desaconsejar sobreescribir un método que se llama `toString` para devolver algo que no sea un `string`. Para eso están los getters y setters.

Comment: Normalmente cuando se pasa un objeto al comboBox el método toString se implementa sólo para retornar el nombre/descripción del elemento que será básicamente lo que se mostraría en el comboBox al momento de hacerle clic, posterior a esto cuando se quiere obtener el valor seleccionado se invoca el método getSelectedElement el cual retona un Object que puede ser casteado a la clase original y desde ahí obtener los otros valores necesarios usando los getters.

Comment: @JonnathanQ Se me acaba de ocurrir algo con lo que dijiste. Voy a intentar y les aviso.

Comment: @JonnathanQ Lo resolví, en el ComboBox solo puse a que cargar un solo elemento, en este caso el nombre y luego cree un objero para que me obtuviera a través del get el codigo del cargo.

Comment: @Permomo me alegro, buen día!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo que separes procesos que tengan funcionalidades diferentes, a continuación te muestro una respuesta y lo entenderas, también te recomiendo que uses nombres que se ajusten mas a la funcionalidad de dicha variable:

```
ResultSet rs;
EstadoCargo empleado ;
ArrayList<empleado> empleados =  new ArrayList<>();

//AÑADIMOS DATOS A UNA COLECCIÓN
        while(estadoCargo.next()){

           empleados.add(new empleado(rs.getString("codigo"), rs.getString("nombre")));
        }
  //VOLCAMOS LOS DATOS EN EL COMBO
        for (int i = 0; i < empleados.size() ; i++) {

            combo.addElement(empleados.get(i).getCodigo)
            combo.addElement(empleados.get(i).getNombre)
            )
        }
```

Es una buena práctica crear un ArrayList de objetos para ir almacenando objetos de la clase puesto que te pueden hacer falta en un futuro, saludos amigo

Answer (score 2):

El uso del método ToString no es el de retornar 2 valores, mas bien se usa para obtener una cadena con el valor de todos los atributos cuando quieres imprimir un objeto, y este debería de llevar @Override, ejemplo:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "conductor{" +
            "nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
            ", fecha='" + fecha + '\'' +
            ", direccion='" + direccion + '\'' +
            ", num_carnet='" + num_carnet + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Ese toString corresponde a una clase que tengo llamada conductor, el cual me permite imprimir un objeto de la clase directamente sin tener que concadenar todos los get (System.out.println(conductor1)), en intellij por ejemplo puedes generarlo automaticamente con boton derecho -> generate -> ToString, si quieres adquirir dos variables prueba a llamar a sus Getters, no veo la necesidad de crear un metodo para ello, saludos ;)

Comment: Amigo, es que con el método String obtengo el valor y luego lo subo a un ComboBox. Pero el problema es que ahora tengo dos variable de tipo string y si las concateno, en el Combo Box me quedan ambas.

Comment: comparte el código en donde añades los valores al combo

Comment: Acabó de editar mi pregunta con el código que añade los valores al combo